# Use an earlier version of MSBUILD

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm trying to build a project using Visual Studio 2013, and I keep running into the following error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1040: ToolsVersion is not valid. The tools version "15.0" is
unrecognized. Available tools versions are "12.0", "14.0", "2.0", "3.5", "4.0".
Switch: 15.0
```

I'm told that I need to upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 in order to fix this, but I'd like to figure-out a way to build projects for the next few days/weeks until I can find time and disk-space to upgrade to 2017.  Is there something I can change on my computer to get my builds to use an earlier version of MSBUILD?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this by changing the tv argument in an rsp file; I assume tv is "tools version"

```
/tv:12.0
```

(changed from 15.0 to 12.0)